WebMvcConfigurer not applied when creating multiple custom context in SpringBoot Tomcat
NOTE:

springboot version 3.3.5
Edited question and Removed ServletContext and used appContext.setParent with Spring ApplicationContext

In my setup, I need to deploy on a separate tomcat web context basis (and I read the name of the contexts from a config file, therefore I removed the default ROOT context). I customized Tomcat using tomcatFactory Bean and using AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext to scan my RESTControllers (which works).
However I noticed although my WebMvcConfigurer is instantiated (I added logging in the constructor), the addInterceptors function isn't executed. This may due to my exclusion of WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class, but if I don't exclude, I'll get this error:
Error creating bean with name 'resourceHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception with message: No ServletContext set
Below is my code:
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = ServletWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration.class)
@ComponentScan({"mynamespace"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {QuartzAutoConfiguration.class, WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class})
public class MySpringBootContainer {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MySpringBootContainer.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(SpringBootContainer.class);
        app.setDefaultProperties(Map.of(
                "spring.config.import", "file:./config.yml")
        );
        app.run(args);
    }

    @Bean
    public TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcatFactory() {
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {

            @Override
            protected TomcatWebServer getTomcatWebServer(Tomcat tomcat) {
                Context webContext = tomcat.addContext("/test1", null);
                Context webContext2 = tomcat.addContext("/test2", null);

                AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
                appContext.setParent(applicationContext);
                appContext.scan("mynamespace");
                appContext.refresh();

                tomcat.getHost().removeChild(tomcat.getHost().findChild("")); // remove default app context

                var dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet(appContext);
                dispatcherServlet.setDetectAllHandlerAdapters(true);
                dispatcherServlet.setDetectAllHandlerExceptionResolvers(true);
                dispatcherServlet.setDetectAllHandlerMappings(true);
                dispatcherServlet.setDetectAllViewResolvers(true);
                Tomcat.addServlet(webContext, "default", dispatcherServlet);
                webContext.addServletMappingDecoded("/*", "default");

                Tomcat.addServlet(webContext2, "default", dispatcherServlet);
                webContext2.addServletMappingDecoded("/*", "default");

                return super.getTomcatWebServer(tomcat);
            }
        });
        return factory;
    }
}


I think the answer is to scan org.springframework.web as well, but that will mean requiring a servlet context, making amendments to the code this way:
...
appContext.setServletContext(webContext.getServletContext());
appContext.scan("org.springframework.web", "mynamespace");
...

But since I am using the same appContext in 2 different context, not sure if setting with just the 1st context's ServletContext will cause any problem / undesirable effects.
